# Using Report Builder and VIsual Studio for reports development

Tags: reporting-services, sql-server-data-tools, reportbuilder3.0

I am in a typical situation where the rdls developed using Reportbuilder dont behave well in Visual Studio. We have mixed set of developers and they use different utilities to develop reports.

Shared data sets and shared data sources are used. However when we use report builder an data sets specification adds relative path to it[image]

[image]

However when I use visual studio it complains and when I re asssign the data set it works. Upon checking the xml file the "/dataset/" is missing.

So here my question is  "Is our assumption of interchangeably using different tools for reports development wrong?" or we are making some stupid mistakes

Comment: RDL is a Microsoft format, so I would guess it's PB doing something funny. That said, the RDL format/tooling has changed for newer versions of the SSDT

Comment: Sorry I used report builder not power builder. I am correcting my post. We are using latest version of SSDT (for VS 2017)

Comment: Per a response to my query in MSDN forum - The observation is correct. The reasoning is ReportBuilder does not store data set locally where as Visual Studio Stores the data sets locally. This is the reason why the path is different.